# Only read a variable if it exists

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the requests module to collect some data from a website. This application runs once every day. The amount of rows of data I get changes every time, per request I can get a maximum 250 rows of data. If there is more then 250 rows of data the API gives me a follow uplink which can be used to get the rows 251 >- 500 etc.

Now I have a problem, sometimes the amount of data is < 250 rows, this means there is no followuplink to use and that's exactly where my program gives the following error:

`KeyError: @odata.nextLink`

**This is a piece of the application:**

```
    proxies = {'https': 'proxy.***.***.com:8080'}
    headers = {"grant_type": "password", 
              "username": "****", 
              "password": "****", 
              "persistent": "true", 
              "device": '{"DeviceUniqueId":"b680c452","Name":"Chrome","DeviceVersion":"36","PlatformType":"Browser"}'}

    url1 = 'https://****-***.com/odata/Results'
   

    params_1 = (
             ('$filter', mod_date),
             ('$count', 'true'),
             ('$select', 'Status'),
             ('$expand', 'Result($select=ResultId),Specification($select=Name), SpecificationItem($select=Name,MinimumValue, MaximumValue)\n\n'),)
    
     response_1 = requests.get(url_1, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, params=params_1)
     q_1 = response_1.json()
    
     next_link_1 = q_1['@odata.nextLink']
     q_1 = [tuple(q_1.values())]
    
     while next_link_1:
         new_response_1 = requests.get(next_link_1, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
         new_data_1 = new_response_1.json()
         q_1.append(tuple(new_data_1.values()))
         next_link_1 = new_data_1.get('@odata.nextLink', None)
```

Now I actually want Python to only read the variable next_link_1 if its available otherwise it should just ignore it and collect what is available...

Comment: It looks like you already have the answer in your code: `new_data_1.get('@odata.nextLink')` (you don't need the `, None` since `None` is already the default default return value for `dict.get`).

Comment: @Iguananaut, but when I debug the program I get the keyerror at the row `next_link_1 = q_1['@odata.nextLink']`.

Comment: Right, so why not use `dict.get` there too?

Comment: Can I do something about the fact that it takes so much time minute to get get output of this in my console? It seems like the server is working really slow

Answer (score 1):

You only want to enter the `while` loop when `q_1` has the key `'@odata.nextLink'` Inside the `while` loop, this is already accomplished in the line `next_link_1 = new_data_1.get('@odata.nextLink', None)` You could use the same approach -- setting `next_link_1` to None if there is no next link -- before the while loop:

```
next_link_1 = q_1.get('@odata.nextLink', None)
```

This can be simplified to

```
next_link_1 = q_1.get('@odata.nextLink')
```

as `None` is already the default default value of `dict.get()`.

NB: The question title is wrong. The variable always exists, as you are setting it. Only the existence of the key `@odata.nextLink` is fragile. So, what you actually want to do is check the existence of a key in a dictionary. To understand what is going on, you should familiarize yourself with the [dict.get()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) method.

There is also some obvious refactoring possible here, getting rid of the repetition of the first iteration, and moving it into the loop:

```
proxies = {'https': 'proxy.***.***.com:8080'}
headers = {
    'grant_type': 'password', 
    'username': '****', 
    'password': '****', 
    'persistent': 'true', 
    'device': '{"DeviceUniqueId":"b680c452","Name":"Chrome","DeviceVersion":"36","PlatformType":"Browser"}'
}
params = (
    ('$filter', mod_date),
    ('$count', 'true'),
    ('$select', 'Status'),
    ('$expand', 'Result($select=ResultId),Specification($select=Name), SpecificationItem($select=Name,MinimumValue, MaximumValue)\n\n'),
)

url = 'https://****-***.com/odata/Results'
data = []
while url:
    response = requests.get(
        url, 
        headers=headers, 
        proxies=proxies, 
        params=params,
    )
    response_data = response.json()
    data.append(tuple(response_data.values()))
    url = response_data.get('@odata.nextLink')
    params = tuple()
```

Comment: So if im right. I should use  next_link_1 = `q_1.get('@odata.nextLink', None)` before the loop but after `q_1`?

Comment: @Premier12 Yes. Or simply `q_1.get('@odata.nextLink')`. But more than that you should start trying to understand what the code you copy-pasted is actually doing :)  That would have enabled you to solve your problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get` in both places. Better yet, restructure your loop so that you only *need* one call.

```
proxies = {'https': 'proxy.***.***.com:8080'}
headers = {...}

url1 = 'https://****-***.com/odata/Results'

params = (...)

qs = []
next_link = url
get_args = {'headers': headers, 'proxies': proxies, 'params': params}
while True:
    response = requests.get(next_link, **get_args)
    q = response.json()
    qs.append(tuple(q.values())
    if (next_link := q.get('@odata.nextLink', None)) is None:
        break
    if 'params' in get_args:
        del get_args['params']  # Only needed in the first iteration
```

---

(I'm not terribly excited about how we ensure `params` is used only on the first iteration, but I think it's better than duplicating the process of defining `next_link` before the loop starts. Maybe something like this would be an improvement?

```
get_args = {...}  # As above
new_get_args = dict(headers=..., proxies=...)  # Same, but without params

while True:
    ...
    if (next_link := ...) is None:
        break
    get_args = new_get_arg
```

Repeated assignment to `get_args` is probably cheaper than repeatedly testing for and deleting the `params` key, at the cost of having a second `dict` in memory. You could even drop that after the first iteration by adding a second assignment `new_get_args = get_args` to the end of the loop, which would result in a pair of do-nothing assignments for later iterations.)